Test Run Results Directory "In" always is empty
I am developing automation tests using MSTest, Selenium and C#. The test results structure is:
Solution\ 
  TestResults\
     DeployDirectory\
                     In\
                       Machine_name\
                                   empty
                     Out\
                        Deploy Files

Test method is decorting with [DeployItem] - so Out directory is not empty:
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("source")]
[Description("ART")]
public void INT0101()
{
  Code...
}

In TestCleanup I take screenshot which goes to Out directory instead of In:
[TestCleanup()]
public void Teardown()
{
    string ScreenshotPath = HelperMethods.TakeScreenshot(driver, this.D365Interface);
    TestContext.AddResultFile(ScreenshotPath);
}

Why In\Machine_name directory is empty? What do I have to do to place something in "In" direcory? Thank you in advance :)
